# Python- Logic for heap data strucure

Tags: python, data-structures

I have created a class to create a max_heap data structure in python.
But the output is not right. I need help

```
import heapq
        
class Max_Heap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap=[]
        
    def parent(self,pos):
        return pos // 2
    
    def left_c(self,pos):
        return (2*pos)+1
    
    def right_c(self,pos):
        return (2*pos)+2
    
    def swap(self,fpos,spos):
        self.heap[fpos],self.heap[spos]=self.heap[spos],self.heap[fpos]
    
    def insert(self,v):
        if(len(self.heap)==0):     
            self.heap.append(v)
        else:
            self.heap.append(v)
            current=len(self.heap)-1
            while(self.heap[current]>self.heap[self.parent(current)]):
                self.swap(current,self.parent(current))
                current=self.parent(current)
                
    def print_heap(self):
        for i in range(0,len(self.heap)):
            print(self.heap[i],end=' ')
        print('\n')

a=Max_Heap()
a.insert(10)
print('Printing heap.....')
a.print_heap()
print('Printing heap.....')
a.insert(12)
a.insert(6)
a.insert(11)
a.insert(46)
a.insert(2)
a.print_heap()
```

The output is :

```
Printing heap.....
46 12 11 10 6 2
```

but the real right answer should be `46,12,6,11,10,2`. Please help to solve this logical error.

Comment: I seriously suggest using some auto formatter (black potentially) and improving the readability of your code. That makes it easier to help you. Also try writing unit tests and isolate the problem yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

something wrong with the parent/left/right definition.

```
Left(0) = 1
Right(0) = 2
Parent(2) = 1
```

Parent(Right(x)) == x, this doesn't hold.

Comment: Didnt fully understand what you meant by your answer.It would be great if you could elaborate.Thanks. PS. I have looked up the defenition online and used it from there

Comment: Could you say what is the right answer/defenition??

Comment: If you going down (left or right) in the heap, and after that you go up, you should return to the same node. This doesn't hold for the root, 0 [right move]==> 2. If you go up from node 2, you would be at node 1.

Answer (score 0):

actually you are on wrong direction,
heapq does a lot of things for u by its own

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush, heapify

heap = []
heapify(heap)

# Adding items to the heap using heappush
heappush(heap, -1 * 12)
heappush(heap, -1 * 6)
heappush(heap, -1 * 46)
heappush(heap, -1 * 2)
heappush(heap, -1 * 11)

# printing the value of maximum element
print("Head value of heap : " + str(-1 * heap[0]))

# printing the elements of the heap
print("The heap elements : ")
for i in heap:
    print((-1*i), end=" ")
print("\n")

element = heappop(heap)

# printing the elements of the heap
print("The heap elements : ")
for i in heap:
    print(-1 * i, end = ' ')
```

Comment: I know about this. But just to test my knowledge I have tried to code the Heap class which would also challenge my skills. Thank You.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).